# Chrome version 48 broke my website layout

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Long time ago I developed a website. It is now slightly old in its design, but it has been working fine. I realize I need to come up with something new, but since it is functional I have kept it.

To my large surprise parts of the page layout suddenly collapsed last week! Some `div` sections just don't show up. Even more surprising is that the problem only exists in Chrome. In Safari, Internet Explorer 11 and Edge it still looks fine.

I am not very skilled in CSS so I just can't figure out what is wrong. Is the standard changed and Chrome is more compliant? Or did Chrome just introduce a change that caused negative sideeffects?

Maybe some of you CSS gurus can just glance and detect a stupid mistake in my layout?

The site is in Swedish, but that should not be a problem. When comparing the layout in Chrome and something else it should be obvious that all the sidepanels on the right are collapsed/invisible in Chrome with only the titles left.

This is the url: http://www.sandeslatt.se

All suggestions are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class name on your elements has the word "adBox" in it, and your adblocker is setting them to `display: none` -- It has nothing to do with Chrome.

Try renaming your class to something without "ad" in it. I know it's silly, but it's how adblock does a lot of the "blocking"

Comment: Aaaah, thanks a lot! So simple, but very misleading :) I had no clue AdBlocker was that stupid.